# Set views exposed filter using url

Tags: 8, views, path-aliases

In a view an exposed filter of type taxonomy reference exists, the referenced taxonomy vocabulary contains about 15 terms, the functionality I'm trying to get is to allow user call view with a default value for filter, so if user enter the path `sitename/view-name/term-name` the view would be load with entities of term `term1`.

I used contextual filter for limiting entities to those having specific `term-name` but the problem is, if user selects another term name, rather than the one specified in contextual filter, the view returns no result (term reference in node accepts only one value).

So I wanted to know if there is a solution to set the exposed filter default value based on url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some research I could found the answer. Actually drupal itself do provide such functionality and there is no need to code or ...

When exposing a field as filter to user, in filter settings window a filter identifier can be set (this can't be empty and is filled with field name by default), this is shown in image below :

[image]

in above example the identifier is set as `cat`, in this situation the path `sitename/view-address/?cat=term-1` will load the view with my exposed filter assigned as term-1 and corespond entities.